# Update multiple column values of a dataframe unconditionally with different variables

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have dataframe with some 10 columns. I have selected 4 columns out of these 10 and cleaned their values(by calling some external API and using its response). I would like to create new dataframe now (as old one cannot be updated) and update these 4 columns with its cleaned value(as returned by the API) and keep other 6 as is.

Tried exploring .na.replace and .withColumn but they all work on some condition for the columns.

```
val newdf = df.withColumn("col1", when(col("col1") === "XYZ", cleanedcol1)
      .otherwise(col("col1")));
```

And

```
val newdf = df.na.replace("col1", Map("col1" -> cleanedcol1))
```

The first snippet matches `col1` value with `XYZ` and then replaces it. I want unconditional change.
The second one actually tries to look for String `"col1"` for `col1` column and hence does not replace anything.

What is the optimum approach to achieve this? The source of the df is Kafka and hence traffic would be fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can have unconditional change with withCoulumn, just write

```
val newdf = df.withColumn("col1", newColumnValue)
```

Where `newColumnValue` is the new value you want to set for the column.